# Handling millions of permutations

Tags: c++, c, performance

I'm trying to compute millions (10<sup>8</sup>) of permutations of a 20x20 boolean matrix. I'm able to compute them quite fast.
After that I need to show this using standard output or store it into a file.
Do you think is possible to manage in some way this amount of data in let's say 4 hours?

Comment: Storing something to a file and displaying it for human consumption are two different things. Are you trying to save the generated data for later use, or have some sort of a report generated based on its characteristics?

Comment: I'm confused.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Why store something that you can calculate (cheaply)?

Comment: Yes, saving it for later use would be the ideal

Comment: `10^18` -> By quite fast, I assume you mean several years? :V

Comment: how long does it take to compute the permutations?

Comment: cheaply is relative to the amount of data, once i make the computation i would to like to access the results immediately

Comment: @Paranoid42: You do realize that `10^18` is a *huge* number, right? If you managed to store one permutation as one byte, you'd need one million 1TB hard drives to do so.

Comment: What are you trying to do that this is your solution?

Comment: 10^18 is more than “millions”. “10^18 individual computations” means that at one nanosecond per computation (3 cycles of a 3GHz computer), you'll have to wait 11574 days.

Comment: it was a typo i meant 10^8

Comment: I don't understand the question. You state that you can "compute them quite fast" - so you already know how long it takes?

Answer (score 4):

10<sup>18</sup> operations? Let's see... Your PC probably does no better than some 10<sup>9</sup> to 10<sup>10</sup> instructions per second. So, you need at least 10<sup>9</sup> to 10<sup>10</sup> seconds to do 10<sup>18</sup> operations, which is over 31 years of time. Is that fast enough? Will your PC be still alive and have uninterrupted power over the course of 31 years?

Comment: I assume it was a mistake though. Billions maybe.

Comment: @perreal I fail to see a difference in the context.

Comment: perhaps you are right

Answer (score 2):

A 20x20 boolean matrix is 400 bits = 50 bytes * 10^8 permutations = 5 * 10^9 bytes = 5 GB.

With a 3 GBit/s SATA drive you have a lower bound of

```
5 GB = 40 GBit / 3 GBit/s ~ 13.3 sec
```

On my 5 year old computer, copying a 1.9 GB file took ~82 seconds. This involved reading and writing 1.9 GB. So, an upper bound for writing a binary representation of your 10^8 400 bit values would be around 215 seconds.

Writing an ASCII representation would use about 50 GB and take around 8-10 times as much time, roughly 2150 seconds. This would be a little more than 35 minutes.

To sum up, I think it should be possible to write this amount of data in less than 4 hours.

**Update**:

I don't have 5 GB main memory to hold all permutations. Therefore, I write the same data multiple times. Calling this with

```
./a.out a.bin 100
```

writes about 4.7 GiB of data and takes 114 seconds on my machine.

```
#include <fstream>

struct matrix {
    unsigned char data[50];
    void write(std::ostream &f) {
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(data));
    }
};

static const unsigned long N = 1000000;
matrix permutations[N];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // prevent sparse file
    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        permutations[j].data[j % 50] = 1;

    std::ofstream f(argv[1]);
    f.sync_with_stdio(false);
    unsigned long m = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            permutations[j].write(f);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using an ASCII representation would look similar

```
struct matrix {
    unsigned char data[50];
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &f, const matrix &x) {
        static int bits[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                f << (x.data[i] & bits[j] ? '1' : '0');
        }

        return f;
    }
};
```

and in `main` the for loop

```
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        f << permutations[j] << '\n';
}
```

Writing 10^7 permutations used about 3.8 GiB on disk and took around 4:41 minutes. Writing ten times that much might take an hour or maybe 90 minutes. On current hardware, this should be faster.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i was trying as plain text, but it seems that it never ends. Can you come with an specific code in cpp on how you would achieve that performance for binary data?

Comment: @Paranoid42 This was just an estimate for how long it might take. Depending on the hardware you have available, this might be longer. But on a current machine, it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

With 10^8 permutations each packed into 50 bytes (400 bits) it would give around 5 GB of data. It should be possible to store that into a file on disk with something like 100 MB per second on an ordinary disk - giving a total write time of 50 seconds for the 5 GB of data.

So provided that you can produce the permutations fast enough, it should be no problem storing them to file in less than the 4 hours specified.